# Is there a way to to call a short code only on a button click using angular js?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress

The following code, it loads once the page is loaded. Once the register button is clicked the wordpress responds with a div saying.  Registration complete but it doesn't reset the form. In this case the page has to be refreshed. Is there a way to refresh the div or call the short code on click of a button? The code is inside a php as well

```
<?php ---------- <div ng-show="someBoolean"><?php echo do_shortcode('[user-meta-registration form="New User"]');?> </div> --------?>
```

Comment: I guess you need to read a little more about the basics of javascript (angular) and php. php is server-sided and cant be called from angular (without reload of the page). but i guess you just want `onclick="location.reload()"`

Comment: Thanks, I know that already.